# Autostart python script not working

Tags: raspbian, python

I have a simple GPIO python script which is working correctly when F5'd from the IDLE3 IDE.

I've followed some instructions to add this to `/etc/profile` but it is not starting:

`sudo python /home/pi/Documents/ScreamerPIR.py &`

I have used this approach in the past and my scripts have started just fine.

- What might stop a particular script starting? (this one uses pygame, whereas my previous scripts did not - could this be it?)
- What approaches can I use to debug my problem?
- Is there a log file anywhere?

Comment: Does it work if you type `sudo python /home/pi/Documents/ScreamerPIR.py &` from the command line?

Comment: Did you check the filename  case sensitivity ? Unlike Windows Linux is case sensitive. General warnings and errors logger can be viewed using `dmseg` . Larger list of available logs are [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/08/linux-var-log-files)

Comment: Thanks both. Calling the script from the Terminal allowed me to see the errors and identify the problem (the path to a Wav file was not relative). Thanks @Joan - if you want to add an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @MarkCooper It's better if you answer the question yourself especially as the steps you took to pinpoint the problem may be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @joan for the steer..

Calling the command from the terminal shows the error message that was the cause of my problem.

`sudo python /home/pi/Documents/ScreamerPIR.py &`

Which in my case was a relative path to a wav file - the relative path works from IDLE IDE, but but when executed from `/etc/profile`